# Angular -- ng-init scope variable not passing into view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I have the following in my index.html

```
   <header>
    <select ng-model="date.month" ng-init="currentMonth" ng-options="month for month in months">
    </select>

    <select ng-model="date.year" ng-init="date.year" ng-options="year for year in years">
    </select>
    </header>
```

I have the following in my app.js

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var today = new Date();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var month = today.getMonth();

    $scope.date = {
        year: year,
        month: month
    };

    $scope.months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    $scope.currentMonth = $scope.months[month - 1];

    var years = [];

    var earliestYear = year - 100;
    for (var i = earliestYear; i <= year; i++) {
        years.push(i);
    }

    $scope.years = years;

    $scope.$watchCollection('date', function (date) {
        $scope.currentDate = new Date(date.year, date.month, 1);
    });
```

My ng-init for "date.year" works, but not for "currentMonth". However, I know currentMonth is connected to the view. Why isn't ng-init recognizing ng-init="currentMonth"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) is an expression so you need to assign `currentMonth` to your `date.month` model.

```
<select ng-model="date.month" ng-init="date.month=currentMonth" ng-options="month for month in months">
</select>
```

The `ng-init="date.year"` doesn't actually do anything. The `date.year` model has already been assigned `2016` so it looks like it works.

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ExdNMtbnbP1xT0bMEU1N?p=preview)